# How to POST binary file to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node.js and coding , I'm trying to upload images to node.js , I follow this , upload binary file to node , test by POSTMAN , but when I choice body/binary in POSTMAN , URL type http://localhost:3000/ ,with api name or not , node always reply

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token �

I check Many answers , try for 6 hours , can't figure it out , please help :(

node app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var multer  =  require('multer');
binary = require('binary');
var http = require('http');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies.
songs = require('./routes/route');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
//////////////////
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     var data = new Buffer('');
     req.on('data', function(chunk) {
         data = Buffer.concat([data, chunk]);
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        req.rawBody = data;
        next();
    });
});
/////////////

app.get('/songs',songs.findAll);
app.get('/findById/:id',songs.findById);
app.post('/songs',songs.addSong);
app.put('/songs/:id',songs.updateSong);
app.delete('/songs/:id',songs.deleteSong);
app.post('/upload',songs.updateSong);
app.get('/upload/:file',songs.viewByFile);
```

route.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var uri = "mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@ds061365.mongolab.com:61365/aweitest";
mongoose.connect(uri);
var multer  =  require('multer');
// we're connected!
var db = mongoose.connection.db;
var BSON = require('bson').BSONPure;
var body = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errrrrrrrror:'));
//db = mongoose.connection.db;
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("mongodb is connected!!");
});


exports.upload = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files.image.originalFilename);
    console.log(req.files.image.path);
    fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {
        var dirname = "/Node/file-upload";
        var newPath = dirname + "/uploads/" +   req.files.image.originalFilename;
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({'response':"Error"});
            } else {
                res.json({'response':"Saved"});
            }
        });
    });
};

exports.viewByFile = function (req, res){
  file = req.params.file;
     var dirname = "/Node/file-upload";
       var img = fs.readFileSync(dirname + "/uploads/" + file);
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
               res.end(img, 'binary');
  };
```

error

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token �
 at parse (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
 at c:\Users\awei\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:116:18
 at invokeCallback (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)
 at done (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)
 at IncomingMessage.onEnd (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\raw- body\index.js:308:7)
 at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
 at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7)
 at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:906:12)
 at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:475:9)
 at process._tickCallback (node.js:389:17)
```

Comment: Please format and clean up your code

Comment: @Oleander sorry , working on it, 3 mins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs/express and binary data in POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503393/nodejs-express-and-binary-data-in-post)

Comment: @Oleander done , really not good at  Indent  try my best

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading binary file on Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598973/uploading-binary-file-on-node-js)

Comment: @GauravDave I'm so confuse , I read it for like ten times , but still have no idea how to fix:(

Comment: why you need to save image file like this

Comment: just save that file into a folder and save the path of that file in your db

Comment: @AtulAgrawal YES! THAT'S I'M TRYING TO DO...I try all day...;(

Comment: you are trying this from postman??

Comment: @AtulAgrawal yes , I use postman try all the api , works fine , but can't upload the image so far

Comment: and why you are not using multer ,it is already been imported in your route.js

Comment: it will make a file object in req object itself

Comment: @AtulAgrawal I try it before , but not succes , postman keep tell me Unexpected token , seems like I need add some at rawbody function at app.post('/upload',songs.updateSong); right?

Comment: clear the cache of postman and then try it or just download an extension of advance restclient in chrome and test it from there

Comment: @AtulAgrawal thank you , working on it ! :D

Comment: i also face the same problem when i was trying to upload an a csv using multer and finally i found that is just because of rest client which caching the file every time and upload all the file at the same time

Comment: @AtulAgrawal I try to open new postman tab , and use multer, it is no longer Unexpected token , but respone a error now! good direction! thank you ! still working on it!

Comment: i am writing this in answer .Please mark this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104521/discussion-between-atul-agrawal-and-awei-hsue).

Answer (score 1):

clear the cache of postman and then try it or just download an extension of advance rest client in chrome and test it from there