# Cannot POST with a binary file to a Node.js Express server

Tags: node.js, express, post, server, postman

I am currently trying to pass a simple text file from `Postman` onto a `Node.js` server in order to save the text file into a folder.
I have replicated the code found on this post: [Using POST data to write to local file with node.js and express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981677/using-post-data-to-write-to-local-file-with-node-js-and-express), however, I keep running into the same error shown here which states "Cannot POST /recieve".

[image: POSTMAN SETUP]

The code I am running is from the post earlier and is:

```
var express = require('express'),

    fs = require('fs')

    url = require('url');

var app = express();

app.use('/public',  express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.post('/receive', function(request, respond) {

    var body = '';

    filePath = __dirname + '/public/data.txt';
    respond.write(__dirname);
    request.on('data', function(data) {

        body += data;

    });

    request.on('end', function (){

        fs.appendFile(filePath, body, function() {

            respond.end();

        });

    });

});

app.listen(8080);
```

I then run `node server.js` in terminal then I POST http://localhost:8080/recieve with a body of a binary file which just contains some numbers.

Someone else was able to get the code working and able to transfer a file with it, however, I cannot find the discrepancy between our programs or methods.

Here is the folder that everything is contained in for reference. Inside `public` is `data.txt` which is the file I am trying to append to.

[image: Folder Setup]

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use a buffer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598973/uploading-binary-file-on-node-js
; Also response.send("Message") is much understandable.

Comment: Also, for sending file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818918/nodejs-sending-uploading-a-local-file-to-a-remote-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled receive incorrectly.

Comment: Ah yes, I made quite a silly mistake quite some time ago. I assure you I won't ever misspell "receive" again.